# How to Match Strings with Apostrophe?

Tags: mysql, match

I have a String with an apostrophe. For example `Mark's House`. In my URL its then named `www.mydomain.com/Marks-House/`.

I want to get a database entry only through the provided name, which is in this case `Marks-House`. So MySQL can't know that there's an apostrophe between `k` and `s` (Mar`k's`).

In my database the entry is saved as `Mark's House` with apostrophe.

My Query:

```
SELECT 
id, title_de AS title, de AS wiki 
FROM pages 
WHERE MATCH (title_de) 
against ('+ Marks-House' in Boolean mode) 
OR title_de LIKE '%Marks-House' LIMIT 1
```

Is it possible to ignore characters like the database apostrophe to match this entry since my URI routing is automatically adding `-` for spaces and removes apostrophes?

Comment: Could you also save the formatted name, as a separate column, in the database record?

Comment: I suppose yes. Would this be more recommended efficient-wise then trying to match it with the suggested solutions of this answer?

Comment: I have no idea about efficiency. I would just want to match the correct domain name given various spellings? There could be domain name to various `formatted aliases` stored. This implies some pre-processing  to identify and store domain names and variants. Or you process the stored original text. As usual, it is a tradeoff of space, time and cost.

Comment: I think I go with your suggestion, even if the given answers aren't wrong. But this is much safer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) to remove the `'` when you're doing your `WHERE`. For example;

```
mysql> select replace("Mark's house", "'", "") as new_value;
+-------------+
| new_value   |
+-------------+
| Marks house |
+-------------+
1 row in set
```

This would make your query the following;

```
SELECT 
id, title_de AS title, de AS wiki 
FROM pages 
WHERE replace(title_de, "'", "") = "Marks-House" LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I got a question. Would you rather recommend adding a new column with the exact matched name to avoid using functions like `LIKE`, `MATCH`, etc. (or `REPLACE` in this case) and be more efficient or isn't this significant?

Comment: @Vay yeah, that would be good, then you could index that field and your search queries will be much more optimised and faster.

Answer (score 1):

A way could be based on  a double like

```
SELECT 
id, title_de AS title, de AS wiki 
FROM pages 
WHERE MATCH (title_de) 
against ('+ Marks-House' in Boolean mode) 
OR title_de LIKE '%Marks%' and title_de like '%House%' LIMIT 1
```

or a multiple %

```
SELECT 
id, title_de AS title, de AS wiki 
FROM pages 
WHERE MATCH (title_de) 
against ('+ Marks-House' in Boolean mode) 
OR title_de LIKE '%Marks%House' LIMIT 1
```

or also a regexp

```
SELECT 
id, title_de AS title, de AS wiki 
FROM pages 
WHERE MATCH (title_de) 
against ('+ Marks-House' in Boolean mode) 
OR title_de REGEXP 'Marks.+House' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution suggestions! In your last example, would that mean that I always have to replace `-` in a string with `.+`? Also, would you rather recommend adding a new column with the exact matched name to avoid using functions like `LIKE`, `MATCH`, etc. and be more efficient or isn't this significant?

Comment: @Vay   no ..you don't need  replace '-'  ...  the dot is a special char for regex  and mean each character .. so the regexp work for Marsk   each char and  House ... hope is clear ..